# Finding out the type signatures of a module/module type, in place

Tags: coq

This issue has been bugging me one too many times now. Is there a way to print the signature of each element of a module type in place in Coq.

For instance:

```
Print Orders.OrderedType.

Module Type Orders.OrderedType = Sig
                               Parameter t
                               Parameter eq
                               Parameter eq_equiv
                               Parameter lt
                               Parameter lt_strorder
                               Parameter lt_compat
                               Parameter compare
                               Parameter compare_spec
                               Parameter eq_dec
                             End
```

---

```
Print Module Type Orders.OrderedType.

Module Type Orders.OrderedType = Sig
                               Parameter t
                               Parameter eq
                               Parameter eq_equiv
                               Parameter lt
                               Parameter lt_strorder
                               Parameter lt_compat
                               Parameter compare
                               Parameter compare_spec
                               Parameter eq_dec
                             End
```

---

```
About Orders.OrderedType.

Module Type Coq.Structures.Orders.OrderedType
```

---

All of these are useless because they do not remind me of the type of each element...

And I can't even use the error messages to remind me, since they are as stupid as:

```
Error: Signature components for label eq do not match.
```

Sure error message, do not tell me the expected type...

I don't know whether this has been fixed in 8.4, but I'd really like a way to not have to look for where this has been defined in order to be reminded how it has been defined. Is there such a thing? :(

---

Especially, finding out the definitions is just chasing along a *ridiculously* long chain of module combinations... Seriously:

```
Module Type OrderedType <: DecidableType := DecStrOrder <+ HasEqDec.
```

Yeah thanks...

```
Module Type DecStrOrder := StrOrder <+ HasCompare.
```

Keep going...

```
Module Type StrOrder := EqualityType <+ HasLt <+ IsStrOrder.
```

...

```
Module Type EqualityType := Eq <+ IsEq.
```

Sure...

```
Module Type Eq := Typ <+ HasEq.
```

Ok...

```
Module Type Typ.
  Parameter Inline(10) t : Type.
End Typ.
```

Finally, I know the type of `t`! \o/

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, this seems to have been fixed in trunk during the past month. Cf.

http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1572

and

http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2466

Comment: I follow the second link of your answer and test with the code has error. They said the code is fixed in trunk. But I do not know where is it exactly? and what is the correct code for this code? I have the same problem with my code so I would like to understand more. Thank you.

Comment: This is the particular commit of the fix: https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=coq&revision=13626 (it's quite annoying that they don't mention it in the bugtracker too...)